# How can I make sure AuthName works in all browsers?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, google-chrome, .htpasswd

The code below appears to show the text "HELLO WORLD" just fine in Firefox, IE, Safari, but not in Chrome.

```
<Files wp-login.php>
AuthType basic
AuthName "HELLO WORLD"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /home/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</Files>
ErrorDocument 401 "Authentication required"
```

How can I make sure AuthName works in all browsers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `AuthName` directive sets the `realm` parameter in the corresponding header, something like:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="HELLO WORLD"
```

I found a Chromium ticket from October 2015 that reports a man in the middle attack related to HTTP authentication: [Issue 544244 - HTTP basic auth credentials prompt should make the origin stand out more](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=544244&q=-has%3Afleet&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified). During the discussion it was pointed out that text in realm can not be trusted and can be used in phishing attacks to trick users into revealing passwords to third-parties. I'm not a security expert but I understand that a proxy can inject headers —and usually does— thus the issue.

Apparent, the realm was removed form the authentication dialogue as a result of this and changes were eventually ported to Chrome. You can see the [Do not show untrustworthy strings in the basic auth dialog](https://codereview.chromium.org/1466473003) code review for further details.

Comment: I noticed it today while modifying Apache configuration. Unfortunately it is not showing even with encrypted connection

Comment: Wish I could override this in my browser settings :/